# Procurar itens no JSONObject

Tags: delphi, pascal

Como pesquisar se o objeto `part_funcionario`
existe no json.

Nesse exemplo não tem mas pode ter json q venha o objeto part_funcionario: [{ key : value}]

```js
{
  "id_participante": 3,
  "id_empresa": 1,
  "nome": "CONSUMIDOR",
  "dt_nasc_criacao": null,
  "ddd1": null,
  "telefone1": null,
  "ddd2": null,
  "telefone2": null,
  "email": null,
  "rg": null,
  "apelido": null,
  "cpf_cnpj": "00000000000",
  "isuf": null,
  "id_crt": null,
  "id_porte_empresa": null,
  "id_tipo_atividade": null,
  "suframa": null,
  "id_contribuinte": null,
  "id_classe": null,
  "numero_original": null,
  "fabricante": false,
  "tipo_participante": 0,
  "participante_ref": null,
  "cod_ref": 4,
  "consumidor_final": true,
  "part_enderecos": [
    {
      "id_part_enderecos": 2,
      "id_participante": 3,
      "id_tipo_endereco": null,
      "id_uf": 29,
      "id_municipio": 1973,
      "id_pais": null,
      "cep": "44001760",
      "tipo_logradouro": "PRAÇA",
      "logradouro": "PRESIDENTE MEDICI",
      "numero": "51",
      "bairro": "CENTRO",
      "complemento": null,
      "cidade_estrangeiro": null,
      "part_enderecos_ref": -1,
      "id_empresa": 1,
      "cod_ref": 4
    }
  ],
  "part_cliente": [
    {
      "id_cliente": 1,
      "id_participante": 3,
      "id_empresa": 1,
      "id_cliente_preco": null,
      "id_cond_pag": 1,
      "id_regiao": 2,
      "limite_credito": 0,
      "conta_credito": 0,
      "conta_debito": 0,
      "id_vendedor": null,
      "desconto_maximo": 10,
      "status": 0,
      "dh_insercao": null,
      "dh_alteracao": "2016-09-14T16:37:20.000Z",
      "cod_ref_cliente": 1,
      "cod_ref": 4
    }
  ],
  "part_contador": [
    {
      "id_contador": 3,
      "id_participante": 3,
      "id_empresa": 1,
      "cod_ref_contador": 0,
      "crc": "17449",
      "cnpj_contabilidade": "14552295000113",
      "status": false,
      "part_contador_ref": -1,
      "cod_ref": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Qual a versão do Delphi?

Answer (score 0):

De forma bem simples você pode **testar** se o ao obter o objeto ele existe.

Algo como:

```
var
  vTeste: TJSONObject;
begin
  vTeste := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(Memo1.Text) as TJSONObject;

  if vTeste.GetValue('part_funcionario') <> nil then
    ShowMessage('Encontrado')
  else
    ShowMessage('Não encontrado');
end;
```

Como na sua pergunta não informa a versão do Delphi utilizada estou instanciando um Json da maneira antiga, mas a forma de obter o valor é a mesma.

Comment: Minha versão é Seatlle, qual seria a outra maneira mais atual?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode testar se conseguiu recuperar o valor usando o TryGetValue.

```
uses
  System.JSON

  valido := json.TryGetValue<String>('part_funcionario', aux);


if(valido)then
   jsonarray := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(aux), 0) as TJSONArray;
```

Comment: Bacana, funcionou, obrigada

Comment: Marcar como respondida!